# Restrict the scale of the search widget in ArcGIS Flex API

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, scale, widget

I wonder if I could restrict the scale scope only for the searching widget (and not the extent of the map)? We want to narrow down the scale for searching in order to avoid too many results which may cause intranet traffic jam.

I am using Adobe Flash Builder and ArcGIS Server 10.2.2.